# How to remove elements below a number in a list of lists using lambda? Python

Tags: python, list

If the values within each list are less than or equal to 2 remove them.

What I have tried:

```
check = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] <= 2, check))
return (output)
```

- expected output

```
[[3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Do you *need* to use `lambda` and `filter` to do this? Did you try using list comprehensions and named functions?

Answer (score 3):

This is a way without using lambda:

```
output = [[y for y in x if y>2] for x in check]
```

Comment: Much simpler and pythonic

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a map to iterate to every list than you apply the filter function.

```
check = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

output = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y > 2,x)), check))
print(output)
```

- output

```
[[3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```